# Find and Replace using Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Well the answer should be very simple.But i am new to the regular expression.

What i want to do is just find and replace :

Eg: iti$%#sa12c@#ombina#$tion.43of//.45simp5./l7e5andsp75e$%cial23$#of%charecters

In the above sentence replace the words "of" with "in"

I tried this but didn't get the result, please help me out.

```
string="iti$%#sa12c@#ombina#$tion.43of//.45simp5./l7e5andsp75e$%cial23$#of%charecters";
var string2=string.replace("/(\w*\W*)of(\w*\W*)/g","$1in$2");
console.warn(string2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not a simple `var replaced = yourString.replace(/of/g, 'in');`?

Comment: This doesn't replace "words", as this would also match "of" when not a complete word.

Answer (score 4):

Fix the [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (no quotes) and use word boundaries (`\b`, no need to use `$1` and `$2`) :

```
var string2 = string.replace(/\bof\b/g, "in");
```

Answer (score 1):

Globally replace without using a regex.

```
function replaceMulti(myword, word, replacement) {
    return myword.split(word).join(replacement);
}

var inputString = 'iti$%#sa12c@#ombina#$tion.43of//.45simp5./l7e5andsp75e$%cial23$#of%charecters';

var outputString = replaceMulti(inputString, 'of', 'in');
```

Comment: Also, this is not Haskell.

Comment: This doesn't replace "words", as this would also match "of" when not a complete word.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are literals or objects in JavaScript, not strings.

So:

```
/(\w*\W*)of(\w*\W*)/g
```

or:

```
new Regexp("(\\w*\\W*)of(\\w*\\W*)","g");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
str.replace("of","in");
```

Comment: This will replace only one occurence, not all

Comment: This also doesn't replace "words", as this would also match "of" when not a complete word.